# Are there any database that support spatial-temporal indexes?

Tags: spatial-index

I am looking for high performant database that support spatial-temporal index. It would be ideal if spacial part of it indexed based on S2 geo library.

Comment: Pretty much all databases support spatial datatypes with spatial indexes. For most, you don't get to choose the indexing algorithm (unless you're on the open-source development team). GIS SE isn't in the software recommendations trade. Within SE, that would be [softwarerecs.se]. We're a *problem-solving* site, not a discussion/opinion one.

Comment: I am looking not just for spatial index, but for the spatial-temporal index, so that 3 dimentions  (lat, long, time) are converted into single index.

Comment: postgis can do 4D https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Temporal also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67905589/how-to-query-space-time-points-with-index-in-postgis

Comment: @Mapperz thank you very much. I think this is what I needed.